# Setting up Pull to Refresh settings during swipe up and down in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, pull-to-refresh

I'm new to Android i would like to know how to set the pull to refresh option like an action bar.
If the pages is swipe down the pull to refresh should be visible, and if its is swiped up it shoud be hidden.
One more thing is the I need to develop the App Exactly like the below screen shot.
It will be help-ful if some one suggest me the idea on developing the application.
Thanks in Advance.
[Pull to Refresh IMage](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5MZNZefeyIxNzBxUjVQVE5sYms/view?usp=sharing)

[My Work](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5MZNZefeyIxR2hmbHVFNW01Y2s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did you already tried something yourself?

Comment: just tried with pull to refresh for refreshing the contents..

Comment: Can you show what you already have?

Comment: please view my update i had attached the screen shot of my work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Pull to Refresh ListView](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView). I have been using this for a month. its good and it has nice samples too otherwise you can use [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) too.